# Centos 6 PHP Upgrade broke apache.

Tags: php, apache, centos6

So I ran the following to upgrade from php 5.3 to 5.5
yum --enablerepo=remi,remi-php55 install php-pecl-apc php-cli php-pear php-pdo php-mysqlnd php-pgsql php-pecl-mongo php-sqlite php-pecl-memcache php-pecl-memcached php-gd php-mbstring php-mcrypt php-xml

Unfortunately it looks like I broke appache which was running PHP as a module not a stand alone service and I have no idea how o roll it back to the module or fix the current settings to make the new service run. I am wondering if theres a way i can undo or roll back the changes from yum history or maybe just get it working.

Any ideas and or help would be much apreciated.

Comment: Did you check your log files? How do you know it's broken? What happens? You haven't really provided any details that would allow anyone to help you.

Answer (score 1):

You should manage to update php 5.3 to 5.5, if you cannot, 
an alternative is using `yum history undo`, first run :

```
yum history
```

Example Output:

```
ID     | Login user               | Date and time    | Action(s)      | Altered
     8 | root <root>              | 2011-10-03 14:40 | Install        |    1   
     7 | root <root>              | 2011-09-21 04:24 | Install        |    1 ##
     6 | root <root>              | 2011-09-21 04:23 | Install        |    1 ##
     5 | root <root>              | 2011-09-16 13:35 | Install        |    1   
     4 | root <root>              | 2011-09-16 13:33 | Erase          |    1   
     3 | root <root>              | 2011-09-14 14:36 | Install        |    1   
     2 | root <root>              | 2011-09-12 15:48 | I, U           |   80   
     1 | System <unset>           | 2011-09-12 14:57 | Install        | 1025
```

Then choose the desired undo, i.e.:

```
yum history undo 2
```

---

SRC:

https://access.redhat.com/solutions/64069

Comment: Interesting command, however I wouldn't recommend this solution for the sole reason that PHP 5.3 is now very old and past its [end of life](http://php.net/eol.php). It would be far better, if possible, to fix the underlying problem.

Comment: I'm inclined to agree with you, although, I was providing an alternative solution, answer updated,  tks for pointing that.